# How to fetch all data in front of a single column in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my code while fetching data of a patient. I want all data of a patient in front of a patient name. For example, I have 5 rows of a patient, I want the patient to fetch patient name and all-time visits in next column.

```
________________________________________
| Name |  Visits Date  |  Product      |
----------------------------------------
| Ali  |  1 May        | test          |
|      |  2 May        | test 2        |
|      |  3 May        | test 3        |
----------------------------------------
```

Here is my code but not working and showing only last column.

```
          <table class="table" border="1" id="data-table5">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Product</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <?php  
              //Fetching Data From DB (Sale)
              $queryex = "SELECT * FROM `dep_sale` GROUP BY `c_name`";
              $result2 = mysqli_query($link, $queryex);
               while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) { ?>  
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $row['c_name']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['frame']; echo ",", $row['size']; echo ",", $row['lense']; ?></td>
                </tr>

              <?php } ?> 
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Please help me in this situation.Thanks

Comment: GROUP BY is incorrectly used. Try your query with phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use it:

```
$queryex = "SELECT `c_name` * FROM `dep_sale` GROUP BY `c_name`";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ORDER BY instead of [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html). If you use GROUP BY you will only have one record per 'cname'

```
<table class="table" border="1" id="data-table5">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Product</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php 
//Fetching Data From DB (Sale)
$queryex = "SELECT * FROM `dep_sale` ORDER BY `c_name` ASC";
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $queryex);
$cname = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    // compare values of $row['cname'] with $cname;
    $name = ($row['cname'] != $cname)? $row['cname'] : '';
?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['visit_date']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    // update $cname value with $row['cname'] within the while loop
    $cname = $row['cname'];
}
?>
```

Sample output:

```
<tr>
  <td>Ali</td>
  <td>1 May</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>2 May</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>3 May</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>4 May</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>peter</td>
  <td>1 May</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>2 May</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>3 May</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>4 May</td>
</tr>
```

Run your original queries

```
"SELECT * FROM `dep_sale` GROUP BY `cname`"
"SELECT * FROM `dep_sale` GROUP BY `cname` ASC"
"SELECT * FROM `dep_sale` GROUP BY `cname` DESC"
```

with phpMyAdmin separately to see different results